# How to get specific value from iTunes API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, itunes

This is my API call:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=cut+the+cord&limit=1

I only want to get the value of the '"releaseDate":"2015-06-29' part.

Is there any way that I could only get that part in a textbox. I have this textbox in another page. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the cross-domaine policy, you must use JSONP to get json data and then format response value:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=cut+the+cord&limit=1",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
        var d = new Date(response.results[0].releaseDate);
        var y = d.getFullYear();
        var m = pad( d.getMonth()+1, 2);
        var d = pad( d.getDate(), 2);
        $("#release").attr('value', y + "-" + m + "-" + d)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yts728L5/2/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: Of course you are right. I was not paying attention. Updated answer.

Comment: @stdob-- thank you so much. That works perfectly. Now, if you don't mind, could you tell me how to get other data such as 'artworkUrl100's value and "collectionName"'s value into two textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're parsing your result as JSON:

```
var result = JSON.parse(apiCallResult)
```

Then, assuming you only have *one* result as in the example request above, you should be able to get that value by simply accessing the object:

```
var results = result.results;
var releaseDate = results[0].releaseDate;
```

This will work if you have multiple results also, but it will only take the first result's releaseDate.

To add the text to a text box, you can use jQuery to get the text box and then set its value:

```
var textBox = $("#myTextBoxId");
textBox.val(releaseDate);
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It perfectly answers the questions.